# Duplicating values and formulas to a new sheet with gspread impossible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, openpyxl, gspread

this has stumped google search and ChatGPT,
Theres actually no why to copy all FORMULAS from one existing sheet to create another one with gspread?
I literally have to download this sheet with openpyxl, then create a new sheet

```
> # Copy the original worksheet's data and formatting to the new worksheet from copy import copy
> 
> for row in default_sheet.rows:
>     for cell in row:
>         new_cell = new_sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column,
>                 value= cell.value)
>         if cell.has_style:
>             new_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
>             new_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
>             new_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)
>             new_cell.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)
>             new_cell.protection = copy(cell.protection)
>             new_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
>             new_cell.value = cell.value
```

And then save this sheet and REUPLOAD into my google drive because gspread does not have the method get_all_values or get_formula or any of the sort
Is this true? Am i dense?
How do I accomplish this without the round about way, I can duplicate a sheet but only its values with:

```
# Set up the API client and authorize it with your credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=gdrive_credentials)

# Open the spreadsheet
spreadsheet = gdrive_client.open("copy")

# Get the original worksheet
original_worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("12/13")

# Get the data from the original worksheet
original_data = original_worksheet.get_all_values()

# Create a new worksheet and give it a name
new_worksheet = spreadsheet.add_worksheet(title="1/1", rows=len(original_data), cols=len(original_data[0]))

# Set the data in the new worksheet
new_worksheet.update('A1', original_data)
```

I've also been trying this method which I have no idea what im doing here:

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# Use the credentials to create a client object
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/Users/k/Downloads/secret-elment-37.json', scope)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)


spreadsheet_id = '16yQw4DjuJpzGgdz3Jk'
mySheetId = '153016'
request_body = {
    'requests': [
        {
            'duplicateSheet': {
                'sourceSheetID': mySheetId,
                'newSheetName': 'TargetSheet'
                }
            }
        ]
    }

response = service.spreadsheet().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId = spreadsheet_id,body=request_body).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `worksheet.copy_range(src_range, dst_range, paste_type='PASTE_FORMULA')`.

For more info: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html.

Hmm, this doesn't allow pasting to a DIFFERENT sheet. For that you'd have to use `duplicate`. Does that do what you want?

`worksheet.duplicate(insert_sheet_index=None, new_sheet_id=None, new_sheet_name=None)`